# Grunt.js: Execute .bat file

Tags: windows, xampp, gruntjs

I would like to start/stop XAMPP via Grunt.js on Windows. There are .bat files to do so: C:\xampp\apache_start.bat and C:\xampp\apache_stop.bat. I haven't found any Grunt plugin which works with the Windows command line.
Is there a plugin able to do this? Or is there any other possibility to start/stop XAMPP via Grunt?

Thanks!

Edit: The solution that I've finally found is [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell).

Comment: Couldn't you do it via PHP, ASP, JSP or any like this? Grunt.js is not that good for this purpose, I think...

Comment: Maybe... I don't know if there is another possibility than using these .bat files to start XAMPP programmatically. I use Grunt for quite a lot of tasks, I would be nice to use it for starting the server, too.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [grunt-commands](https://github.com/luozhihua/grunt-commands)??

looks like it can execute .bat file in windows

```
command : {
    run_shell: {
        type : 'shell',
        cmd  : './test.sh'
    },
    run_bat: {
        type : 'bat',
        cmd  : 'test.bat'
    },
    run_cmd: {
        cmd: ['mkdir __tmp__cmd', 'mkdir __tmp__']
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. When I try to install it via "npm install grunt-commands --save-dev", I get the message 'grunt-commands' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: try 'grunt-contrib-commands', seems like the author didn't rename this pkg to grunt-commands

Comment: The installation worked. But executing commands doesn't seem to work. I placed a test.bat file in the directory with all my grunt plugins. Just so see if it works. This file basically creates a directory called 'test'. When I execute the .bat file directly (by double-clicking on it), the directory is created.
I don't get any error message...

Comment: have you tried to execute .bat file thro command line? does this work?

Comment: Yes, that works just as expected. The .bat file is fine.

Comment: There's another way you may want to try. Register a task and use [grunt.util.spawn](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.util#grunt.util.spawn) method. FYI [example](http://tom-jaeschke.blogspot.tw/2013/10/use-utilspawn-in-grunt-build.html)

Comment: This didn't work out for me... the solution that I finally found is [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell). Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

grunt-commands is not working. Or author forget to tell us something special about it in comments.... 
It's "Free soft" what else to tell...